# Show image after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have a controller method that returns image in byte array, from MongoDB, and I want to show it in my view:

```
<HttpPost()>
        Function ShowImage(id As String) As FileContentResult

            Dim Handler = New MongoDBHandler()
            Dim newString = id.Replace(vbLf, "").Trim().Replace("""", String.Empty)
            Dim byteArray = Handler.ReadImage(newString)

            Return File(byteArray, "image/png")
        End Function
```

I have the javascript function:

```
function postCardNumber(elm) {

            var CardNumber = $(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html();

            var $img = $('<img>');
            $img.attr("src", "/MyController/MyMethod/CardNumber");
            $("#myModal").append($img);

            }
```

The Table:
[image]

When the "Show" button click, on the table, the "No." cell (and is data) is sent to the JS function, and pass to the controller, then i try to create new image element with, and add it to my popup modal for show.
The problem is i cant get the controller response, and spent hours in google search for it, any solutions please?

Comment: Shouldnt `"/MyController/MyMethod/CardNumber"` be `"/MyController/MyMethod/"+CardNumber`? Otherwise you send the string "CardNumber" to the server

Comment: thats the way to talk the controller method ?

Comment: But don't you want to send e.g. `"/MyController/MyMethod/364091670"`?

Comment: yes, but the number is changing on every click, i need pass parameter.

Comment: right, and you have the id in the variable `CardNumber`, but you never use it.

Comment: I try to pass it to the controller method.

Comment: You set the image-source to the URL `"MyController/MyMethod/CardNumber"`, where "CardNumber" is indeed just the text "CardNumber" and not the value in the variable `CardNumber`,

Comment: I try: "/MyController/MyMethod/"+CardNumber" but didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following and check if it work. Please verify that the controller name you are specifying in following URL is correct.
I am not sure that your controller name is "MyController". check it and change if it is wrong.
If following code doesn't work, send me the `url` it generated in comment

function postCardNumber(elm) {

```
        var CardNumber = $(elm).closest("tr").find(".card-number").html();

        var $img = $('<img>');
        $img.attr("src", "@(Url.Action("ShowImage","CreditCard"))/" + CardNumber);
        $("#myModal").append($img);

        }
```

Comment: Thx on help.I have that error: [link](https://s29.postimg.org/6rw8yp5rb/error.png)
My controller name is: "CreditCard", and method: "ShowImage"
Additionally i use VB not C#.

Comment: I put breakpoint on ShowImage function, but it didnt reach it.

Comment: remove <HttpPost> as it is a GET operation

Comment: Put get or just remove?

Comment: just remove the <httppost> and try

Comment: Thx god, its reach the controller